# jQuery Uncaught TypeError with offset().left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code, visually anyway, works fine, but I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read property 'left' of undefined" in my console.  I have no clue what might be causing it.

Specifically, the error is showing up on the following: line:

```
var left = $(this).siblings('li.active').offset().left - ($(this).parents('.hoverBar').offset().left + 20);**
```

The whole function for context:

```
 $('.hoverBar li').hover(function(){

        var left = $(this).offset().left - ($(this).parents('.hoverBar').offset().left + 20);
        var width = $(this).width() + "px";
        var sictranslate = "translate("+left+"px, 0px)";

        $(this).parent('ul').next('div.floatr').css({
            "width": width,
            "-ms-transform" : sictranslate,
            "-webkit-transform": sictranslate,
            "-moz-transform": sictranslate,
            "transform": sictranslate
        });

    },

    function(){

        var left = $(this).siblings('li.active').offset().left - ($(this).parents('.hoverBar').offset().left + 20);**
        var width = $(this).siblings('li.active').width() + "px";

        var sictranslate = "translate("+left+"px, 0px)";

        $(this).parent('ul').next('div.floatr').css({
            "width": width,
            "-ms-transform" : sictranslate,
            "-webkit-transform": sictranslate,
            "-moz-transform": sictranslate,
            "transform": sictranslate

        });

    }).click(function(){

        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;

    });
```

And some relevant HTML:

```
<nav class="head_nav">
<div class="hoverBar">
<ul id="navbar">
            <li class="active"><a href="">About</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Board Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Task Forces</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="">Events</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Registration with Outlook ICS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Online Payment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Email auto-reminders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Multiple registrants allowed</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="floatr"></div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: When your selector did not match any elements, `.offset()` returns `null`.

Comment: When `$(this).siblings('li.active')` does not exist (undefined) its `.offset().left` property cannot be read (because non-existent objects naturally can't have properties)

Comment: What line does your console point to specifically? You are looking for offset in a few places. Anyways, usually when this error occurs it is often a scope issue and JavaScript can't find the object you are looking for offset on. So my first suggestion would be to `console.log($(this));` and make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Kris,  it points to this line:

var left = $(this).siblings('li.active').offset().left - ($(this).parents('.hoverBar').offset().left + 20);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code to a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mswieboda/F4fnf/ and on line 16 you needed to add `.parents('.hoverBar').find('li.active')` like this:

```
var left = $(this).parents('.hoverBar').find('li.active').offset().left - 
    ($(this).parents('.hoverBar').offset().left + 20);
```

This is because the hovered element `$(this)`: `.hoverBar > ul > li > ul > li > a` was not a sibling of `.hoverBar > ul > li.active` you were trying to navigate to in the DOM.

This fixed the JS error you were receiving with trying `.offset()` on `undefined` since that jQuery element didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is when a selector has no elements, offset returns `undefined`. Just wrap your code into

```
var $siblings = $(this).siblings('li.active');
if ($siblings.length) {
    var left = $siblings.offset().left 
             - ($(this).parents('.hoverBar').offset().left + 20);
    var width = $siblings.width() + "px";

    //...
}
```

This way your selector is cached into the variable `$siblings` and doesn't run twice or more.